# Dockerfile COPY failed with particular directory name

Tags: docker, dockerfile

A normal COPY line in my Dockerfile is preventing the image from being built.

```
COPY privoxy.config /etc/privoxy/config/
```

The log says

```
failed to copy files: failed to create new directory: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6748c046ce142595c7d4fec886898f88abf9a932876b80b436ea5fd24b705a5/merged/etc/privoxy/config: not a directory
```

Just want to figure out why this peculiar problem happens. I've made sure the dest path is with the trailing slash and tried to change the path name, the problem dissappered when I changed the `config` in the dest path to `conf`. I've also presumed it was related to the `privoxy.config` extension name but after experiment it was not the case.

Comment: How you build your Dockerfile?

Comment: @potiev docker build -t image_name .

Comment: Which user is active, when you do copy? root or a limited one?

Comment: @Maik root. Obviously it copies when the build proceeds to the COPY command.

Comment: Does an `/etc/privoxy/config` _file_ (not a directory) exist in the image, before this `COPY` step?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you very much that's exactly the case! Would you please write an answer to this problem? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COPY` will create the destination directory in the image if it doesn't already exist.  However, if the destination already exists but it's a file (or something else that's not a directory) you can get this error.

You can verify this with a temporary container:

```sh
docker run --rm the-base-image \
  ls -ld /etc/privoxy/config
```

If the destination is a file, and you want to `COPY` that source file to that specific image file, then you can remove the `/` at the end of the path to cause Docker to overwrite the existing file.

```sh
COPY privoxy.config /etc/privoxy/config  # <-- no trailing /
```